# Implementing SNMP agent on embedded system

Tags: networking, embedded, snmp, agent

I am currently developing an embedded uP based appliance which can be remotely controlled via ethernet from a PC using its own SNMP manager software.

I have implemented all the private commands, i.e. using a private community password and under the enterprise tree OID (1.3.6.1.4.1.MY_PEN...etc) So from that point of view the unit is working OK.

What I am not too sure is whether the appliance should also respond to other SNMP OID branch queries (e.g. 1.3.6.1.2.1...or others ) Not for the benefit of my PC software, but for the benefit of other PC managers who may or may not want to know whether my device "exists" on the system.

I am aware this is not an essential requirement (my device doesn't need to be known to others) but perhaps there is an established "polite" requirement for SNMP agents in a network to be visible as such. In which case there may be a minimum subset of OID queries that such agents should at least respond to to any PC manager out there.

I cannot find anything about this on the internet, does such a thing exist?

Any comments (or at least a pointer to the "right" RFC as there are so many of them!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For devices that I've worked on, the MIB-II system group (sysName, sysLocation, etc) is usually implemented. Other standards are only implemented where a definite need exists. See [RFC 1213](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1213).

Comment: Yes Thanks, this is more or less what I have found out from various searches on the web. Although only the mib-2.system branch is implemented and not the others.